# Linux: Add new line with character and increasing number to file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file with many lines (~40 million) that I'm trying to split up for use in some downstream processes. The file looks like this

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

I'd like to break up the file by adding the string '>n' in a new line every 1M lines. For these purposes a 2 line example would be fine. I'd like my final output to be

```
a
b
>1
c
d 
>2
e
```

I'm pretty sure sed can accomplish this but I can't manage to get the increasing number part figured out.

Comment: *I'd like to split the file* - split the file into multiple files OR to just insert `'>n'` after each million line?

Comment: just insert >n after each 1M lines. In the software I'm using downstream '>' indicates a split.  Perhaps 'break up' the file is a better term

Comment: awk would be better choice than sed...

Comment: If you are attempting to split a FASTA file, explaining your precise requirement might help you achieve your actual final goal faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk is the better choice here.

This one inserts the line like you wish

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}; {if ((NR-1) % 1000000 == 0) {i++; print ">" i}}; {print}' your_file > another_file
```

This one splits the file "your_file" directly into files named "your_file1", "your_file2", and so on.

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=0}; {if ((NR-1) % 1000000 == 0) {i++}} {print > "your_file" i}' your_file
```

Comment: you could add  && NR>1 in your condition too else it will take first line too in it.

Answer (score 4):

@Stephen: try:

```
awk -v num=2 'FNR % num == 0 {print $0 ORS ">"++q ;next} 1'  Input_file
```

Similarly, you could provide your line number above and could print it then in output. Also I have put as FNR to find number of line in case user is using multiple Input_files so each time when next file comes it will RESET the FNR's value and it will start from scratch for next Input_file(which NR doesn't do).

EDIT: Adding complete explanation of code too now.

```
awk -v num=2           #### Setting a variable named num to value 2 here.
'FNR % num == 0        #### Checking condition if FNR%num==0 is TRUE then it should perform following actions. Where FNR is awk built-in keyword to get the line number, only difference between FNR and NR is FNR gets RESET whenever a new Input_file gets read. As we know awk could read multiple Input_files, so
                            in this case FNR could be really helpful compare to NR.
{print $0 ORS ">"++q ; #### printing the current line's value(off course when above condition is TRUE) with ORS(output field separator) whose default value is new line and then printing ">" and a variable named q whose value will always increase each time cursor comes in this section.
next}                  #### mentioning next keyword here which will help us to skip all other further statements when this condition met so that we could save our time.
1                      #### awk works on condition then action pattern so here by putting 1 I am making condition as TRUE and then specifying no action so by default print will happen which will print the entire line.
'  Input_file          #### mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: this answer would be even better if the commands were explained. for instance `-v var=num` assigns the variable num to var before the program begins. explain what FNR does and ++q

Comment: I think I just added the explanation on same time you commented :)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 seq -f'>%g' 1000000 | sed '0~1000000R /dev/stdin' file
```

This uses `seq` to generate a sequence of as many file dividers as you think necessary and then inserts them into the input file using the modulo operation `from~step`.

Another way, which is totally sed but not recommended is:

```
sed -r '0~1000000!b;p;x;s/^9*$/0&/;:a;s/9(x*)$/x\1/;ta;s/$/#0123456789/;s/(.)(x*)#.*\1(.).*/\3\2/;s/x/0/g;h;s/^/>/' file
```

This uses the same modulo operation and then keeps a counter in the hold space and increments it before it inserts it into the output file.

However. As the real intention of this exercise is to `split` a large file into smaller ones, why not just use `split`?

```
split -a1 --numeric-suffixes=1 -l 1000000  file '>'
```

This splits file into files named `>1`..`>n` each of a million lines.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sed can do it all by itself, since (AFAIK) it can't handle variables, but awk can. You can use the following script

```
BEGIN {
    id=0;    
}

{
    if (NR % nth == 0) {
        print ">"id;
        id++;    
    } else {
        print $0
    }
}

END {}
```

then execute it this way:

```
awk -v nth=<your N value> -f /script/name > /new/file
```

Comment: `id=1` to match OP's expected output... you also need to print `$0` when `NR % nth == 0`.. or just print it always and then check condition... can be simplified to `awk -v nth=2 '{print} NR%nth==0{print ">" ++c}' file`

Comment: This isnt quite what he want, this would **replace** the nth line with ">"

Comment: @putonspectacles no, it replaces it with ">id".

Answer (score 0):

I wolud do this with a simple shell-script (upline.sh):

```
EVERYLINE=2

LINECOUNT=0
COUNTER=1

#read file line by line
while read LINE; do

    #print current line
    echo $LINE

    #increment linecounter
    ((LINECOUNT++))

    #check if we have to insert an additional line
    if [ $LINECOUNT -eq $EVERYLINE ]; then
        #print additional line
        echo ">n$COUNTER"

        #increment counter for additional line
        ((COUNTER++))

        #reset linecounter
        LINECOUNT=0
    fi
done
```

Start it with

```
bash upline.sh < youtdatafile.txt
```

The variable "EVERYLINE" controls after how many line the extra line will be inserted. 
You could also use

```
EVERYLINE=$1
```

to give the "split-number as parameter.